# express-jwt authentication middleware not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, express, mean-stack

I'm using `express-jwt` for athentication, and the following is my code:

`api>routes/index.js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({ secret: 'thisIsSecret', requestProperty: 'auth' });
```

after this inside `index.js` when i use `auth` middleware in

```
router.post('/locations/:locationId/reviews', auth, ctrlReviews.reviewsCreate);
```

route, when want to post reviews data with post-man, request goes to loading, and no response appear, but if remove `auth` from route request give response.
I have also checked with

```
var auth = jwt({
  secret: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
  userProperty: 'payload'
});
```

Comment: Your express-jwt logic works for me. Are you sending a valid JWT within the Authorization header in Postman?

Comment: @dan I want to check the `unautorizedError` and catched that in `app.js` something like `app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
  if (err.name === 'UnauthorizedErorr') {
    res.status(401);
    res.json("message : " + err.name + " : " + err.message);
  }
});` and expect a message response.

Comment: @dan Sorry, checked again i have a type mistake in `app.js` (`UnauthorizedErorr `). Thank u

Comment: Ok, I've posted an answer to show an example of that. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you're trying to handle valid and invalid tokens. This should be possible with something similar to the below code.

If you use Postman to call this with the following header, then you'll receive 200 OK, with a message of 'OK!'.

```
Authorization: Bearer validJWT
```

If you use Postman to call this without a valid JWT then you'll receive 401 Unauthorized with a message of 'invalid token...'.

```
var jsonwebtoken = require('jsonwebtoken');
var express = require('express');
var app  = express();

var jwt = require('express-jwt');
var auth = jwt({ secret: 'thisIsSecret', requestProperty: 'auth'});

// Generate valid JWT
console.log(jsonwebtoken.sign({ foo: 'bar' }, 'thisIsSecret'));

app.post('/locations/:locationId/reviews', auth, function(req, res, next) {
    // Log user details set in JWT
    console.log(req.auth)
    res.send('OK!');
});

// Handle invalid JWT
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    if (err.constructor.name === 'UnauthorizedError') {
        res.status(401).send('invalid token...');
    }
});

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('Server running on 3000')
})
```